# How does Facebook make personal named pages?

Tags: php, facebook, url, uri

Hey guys hope all is good and here's my question: When you click on a Facebook profile the address bar shows the URI named after the account's owner, for example:

Name: John Smith
Facebook URI: facebook.com/john.smith

The question is, how is this achieved to dynamically name a page based on the name of each user. I do not believe Facebook would make a directory named after each user and then add the same html, css, scripts etc in every directory... So if I decided to make a member's page in PHP how would I go about naming it depending on the user's name?

All constructive answers welcome and have a nice day.

Comment: Get the username as it is and add any prefix before.

Comment: That would take you to an undefined directory...

Answer (score 1):

If you have used any frameworks before, you'd be familiar with the concept of routing.

I will give you a rough idea which can be reproduced in any framework. There is an assumption that I will make: *You have a table which is storing the user's details and it has a field for the custom URL slug.*

Now the logic:

1. Let's say you have a route configured like `website.com/user/mr.xyz`.
2. This means that the route for `user/query` will be set to a controller like `User(query)`.
3. Now, you check the query value and see if it is present in your database with the customized URL field.
4. If it matches, then you load that user's profile.

### Update

You should see [how routes work in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/routing). If you are not aware of frameworks, then you should learn one to understand how these things work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I am looking into that as we speak. Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: Laravel is great! Only php framework that I like, much easier to use than others! Blade for forms and templating is great too!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually acheived through a rewrite module such as apache's mod_rewrite.
This internally changes (rewrites) the url from domain.com/profilename to something like domain.com/profile.php?profile=profilename. You can then access the query parameter using $_GET['profile']. This is actually a feature of apache and not PHP.

The rewrite happens on the server so the browser will still display the friendly url to the user.

Here is a more in-depth article/tutorial.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/?search_index=13

Good luck

Comment: Beautifully explained, I am very grateful. Thank you very much.